# sorting file having fixed field width bash

Tags: bash, sorting

My input may be any of the given two types.
First one
Each field is of width 20

```
                2019              Autumn              CS 753                   6 Department elective                  AB
                2019              Autumn              CS 490                   6         Honors core                  CC
                2019              Autumn              CS 492                   6         Honors core                  FR
                2019              Autumn              CS 747                   6 Department elective                  FF
                2019              Autumn              ES 200                   3      Basic Sciences                  BC
```

Second one

```
^[[40m^[[33m                2019              Autumn              CS 753                   6 Department elective                  AB^[(B^[[m
^[[40m^[[37m                2019              Autumn              CS 490                   6         Honors core                  CC^[(B^[[m
^[[40m^[[37m                2019              Autumn              CS 492                   6         Honors core                  FR^[(B^[[m
^[[40m^[[33m                2019              Autumn              CS 747                   6 Department elective                  FF^[(B^[[m
^[[40m^[[36m                2019              Autumn              ES 200                   3      Basic Sciences                  BC^[(B^[[m
```

first file with color
I want to sort them with respect to third field that is field containing CS 490 etc.
Coloured inputs should give coloured outputs.
Expected output for input 1

```
                2019              Autumn              CS 490                   6         Honors core                  CC
                2019              Autumn              CS 492                   6         Honors core                  FR
                2019              Autumn              CS 747                   6 Department elective                  FF
                2019              Autumn              CS 753                   6 Department elective                  AB
                2019              Autumn              ES 200                   3      Basic Sciences                  BC
```

Likewise for input 2

```
^[[40m^[[37m                2019              Autumn              CS 490                   6         Honors core                  CC^[(B^[[m
^[[40m^[[37m                2019              Autumn              CS 492                   6         Honors core                  FR^[(B^[[m
^[[40m^[[33m                2019              Autumn              CS 747                   6 Department elective                  FF^[(B^[[m
^[[40m^[[33m                2019              Autumn              CS 753                   6 Department elective                  AB^[(B^[[m
^[[40m^[[36m                2019              Autumn              ES 200                   3      Basic Sciences                  BC^[(B^[[m
```

How can i get this in bash.
I can sort first input by doing `sort -k3,4`
And the second one by `sort -k4,5`
But the problem arises when it can be any of the above.

Comment: what have you tried so far? have you tried using the `sort`? command? here are some samples: [sample1](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/151191-sorting-fixed-width-seq-file.html), [sample2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16998627/7366100); [sample3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18193392/7366100)

Comment: I have edited question please look at it.

Comment: what do you get as output when you run your `sort` commands? what do you mean by 'problem arises when it can be any of the above'? **what** problem are  you referring to?

Comment: My input can be any of the two for same script, then first command will not work for second one and vice versa

Comment: can a single file contain both formats?  for the color files ... is `^[` a literal string of 2x characters or is it an actual control character?

Comment: I'd do your first sort by position, not field: `sort -k41,60 <file>`

Comment: No a single file can't contain both  fromat. Coloured file is obtained by adding those characters to the first input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provisos and assumptions:

- input files can be one of two formats: 1) without color codes, 2) with color codes
- a file will not contain both formats
- for files with color formats the first character in the line is the single character Ctrl-[ (ie, it is **not** the 2x characters '^' + '[')

For the sake of this answer we'll name the files:

- `file1` - contains no color characters
- `file2` - contains color characters

One solution using `sort` to order by fields 3,4 (non-color) or fields 4,5 (color)

```
for f in file1 file2
do
    echo "+++++++++++++++++ ${f}"
    pat='-k3,4'                                                  # define `sort` pattern for non-color file
    [[ $(head -1 ${f} | cut -c1) =~ $'\c[' ]] && pat='-k4,5'     # if first character of first line is `Ctrl-[` (ie, $'\c[') then define `sort` pattern for color file
    sort ${pat} ${f}                                             # sort the file
done
```

Running the above generates:

```
+++++++++++++++++ file1
            2019              Autumn              CS 490                   6         Honors core                  CC
            2019              Autumn              CS 492                   6         Honors core                  FR
            2019              Autumn              CS 747                   6 Department elective                  FF
            2019              Autumn              CS 753                   6 Department elective                  AB
            2019              Autumn              ES 200                   3      Basic Sciences                  BC                 AB
+++++++++++++++++ file2
            2019              Autumn              CS 490                   6         Honors core                  CC
            2019              Autumn              CS 492                   6         Honors core                  FR
            2019              Autumn              CS 747                   6 Department elective                  FF
            2019              Autumn              CS 753                   6 Department elective                  AB
            2019              Autumn              ES 200                   3      Basic Sciences                  BC
```

**NOTE**: The last 3 lines of output for `file2` show with color in my console.

To show color formatting codes: `sort ${pat} ${f} | cat -v`

```
+++++++++++++++++ file1
                2019              Autumn              CS 490                   6         Honors core                  CC
                2019              Autumn              CS 492                   6         Honors core                  FR
                2019              Autumn              CS 747                   6 Department elective                  FF
                2019              Autumn              CS 753                   6 Department elective                  AB
                2019              Autumn              ES 200                   3      Basic Sciences                  BC
+++++++++++++++++ file2
^[[40m^[[37m                2019              Autumn              CS 490                   6         Honors core                  CC^[(B^[[m
^[[40m^[[37m                2019              Autumn              CS 492                   6         Honors core                  FR^[(B^[[m
^[[40m^[[33m                2019              Autumn              CS 747                   6 Department elective                  FF^[(B^[[m
^[[40m^[[33m                2019              Autumn              CS 753                   6 Department elective                  AB^[(B^[[m
^[[40m^[[36m                2019              Autumn              ES 200                   3      Basic Sciences                  BC^[(B^[[m
```

Comment: It is working. Only thing I can't understand is your third assumption. I don't know about control character.

Comment: `head -1 file2 | cut -c1-2 | od -c` will output '033' if the first character in the file is the control character `Ctrl-[`, or it will output `^` and `[` if it's not a single control character